# Reading mp3 file using ffmpeg caues memory leaks, even after freeing it in main

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, memory-leaks, mp3

i am continuously reading mp3 files and processing them, but the memory keeps getting build up even though i freed it.

At the bottom `read_audio_mp3()`, they are already freeing some variable.
why do i still face a memory build up and how do i deal with it ?

following this code : https://rodic.fr/blog/libavcodec-tutorial-decode-audio-file/, i read mp3 using this function

```cpp
    int read_audio_mp3(string filePath_str, const int sample_rate, 
      double** output_buffer, int &AUDIO_DURATION){
      const char* path = filePath_str.c_str();

      /* Reads the file header and stores information about the file format. */
        AVFormatContext* format = avformat_alloc_context();
        if (avformat_open_input(&format, path, NULL, NULL) != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file '%s'\n", path);
            return -1;
        }

      /* Check out the stream information in the file. */
        if (avformat_find_stream_info(format, NULL) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not retrieve stream info from file '%s'\n", path);
            return -1;
        }

      /* find an audio stream. */
        int stream_index =- 1;
        for (unsigned i=0; i<format->nb_streams; i++) {
          if (format->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
            stream_index = i;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (stream_index == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not retrieve audio stream from file '%s'\n", path);
            return -1;
        }
        AVStream* stream = format->streams[stream_index];

      // find & open codec
        AVCodecContext* codec = stream->codec;
        if (avcodec_open2(codec, avcodec_find_decoder(codec->codec_id), NULL) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open decoder for stream #%u in file '%s'\n", stream_index, path);
            return -1;
        }

      // prepare resampler
        struct SwrContext* swr = swr_alloc();
        av_opt_set_int(swr, "in_channel_count",  codec->channels, 0);
        av_opt_set_int(swr, "out_channel_count", 1, 0);
        av_opt_set_int(swr, "in_channel_layout",  codec->channel_layout, 0);
        av_opt_set_int(swr, "out_channel_layout", AV_CH_LAYOUT_MONO, 0);
        av_opt_set_int(swr, "in_sample_rate", codec->sample_rate, 0);
        av_opt_set_int(swr, "out_sample_rate", sample_rate, 0);
        av_opt_set_sample_fmt(swr, "in_sample_fmt",  codec->sample_fmt, 0);
        av_opt_set_sample_fmt(swr, "out_sample_fmt", AV_SAMPLE_FMT_DBL,  0);
        swr_init(swr);
        if (!swr_is_initialized(swr)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Resampler has not been properly initialized\n");
            return -1;
        }

      /* Allocate an audio frame. */
        AVPacket packet;
        av_init_packet(&packet);
        AVFrame* frame = av_frame_alloc();
        if (!frame) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating the frame\n");
          return -1;
        }

      // iterate through frames
        *output_buffer = NULL;
        AUDIO_DURATION = 0;
        while (av_read_frame(format, &packet) >= 0) {
          // decode one frame
            int gotFrame;
            if (avcodec_decode_audio4(codec, frame, &gotFrame, &packet) < 0) {
              // free packet
                av_free_packet(&packet);
                break;
            }
            if (!gotFrame) {
              // free packet
                av_free_packet(&packet);
                continue;
            }
          // resample frames
            double* buffer;
            av_samples_alloc((uint8_t**) &buffer, NULL, 1, frame->nb_samples, AV_SAMPLE_FMT_DBL, 0);
            int frame_count = swr_convert(swr, (uint8_t**) &buffer, frame->nb_samples, (const uint8_t**) frame->data, frame->nb_samples);
          // append resampled frames to output_buffer
            *output_buffer = (double*) realloc(*output_buffer,
             (AUDIO_DURATION + frame->nb_samples) * sizeof(double));
            memcpy(*output_buffer + AUDIO_DURATION, buffer, frame_count * sizeof(double));
            AUDIO_DURATION += frame_count;
          // free buffer & packet
            av_free_packet(&packet);
            av_free( buffer );
        }

      // clean up
        av_frame_free(&frame);
        swr_free(&swr);
        avcodec_close(codec);
        avformat_free_context(format);

      return 0;
    }
```

Main Script : `MemoryLeak.cpp`

```cpp
    // imports
      #include <fstream>
      #include <stdio.h>
      #include <stdlib.h>
      #include <string.h>
      #include <math.h>
      #include <iostream>
      #include <sstream>
      #include <vector>
      #include <sys/time.h> 
      extern "C"
      {
      #include <libavutil/opt.h>
      #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
      #include <libavformat/avformat.h>
      #include <libswresample/swresample.h>
      }
      using namespace std;

    int main (int argc, char ** argv) {
      string wavpath = argv[1];
      printf("wavpath=%s\n", wavpath.c_str());

      printf("\n==== Params =====\n");
      // Init
        int AUDIO_DURATION;
        int sample_rate = 8000;
        av_register_all();

      printf("\n==== Reading MP3 =====\n");
        while (true) {
            // Read mp3
              double* buffer;
              if (read_audio_mp3(wavpath, sample_rate, &buffer, AUDIO_DURATION) != 0) {
                printf("Cannot read %s\n", wavpath.c_str());
                continue;
              }

            /* 
              Process the buffer for down stream tasks.
            */

            // Freeing the buffer
            free(buffer);
        }

      return 0 ;
    }
```

Compiling

```cpp
    g++ -o ./MemoryLeak.out -Ofast -Wall -Wextra \
        -std=c++11 "./MemoryLeak.cpp" \
        -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil -lswresample
```

Running, by right my input an argument `wav.scp` that reads text file of all the mp3s.
But for easy to replicate purpose, i only read 1 file `song.mp3` in and i keep re-reading it

```sh
./MemoryLeak.out song.mp3
```

Why do i know i have memory leaks?

1. I was running up 32 jobs in parallel for 14 million files, and when i wake up in the morning, they were abruptly killed.
2. I run `htop` and i monitor the progress when i re-run it, and i saw that the `VIRT` & `RES` & `Mem` are continuously increasing.

> Edit 1:
> My setup :

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
built with gcc 5.4.0
```

Comment: I don't see `buffer` ever getting freed.

Comment: @RetiredNinja : Actually i was thinking about that too, but the same thing happens even if i freed it in the main script. i have edited the questions to reflect the freeing, but the memory leak problem still exists...

Comment: If possible you should run your application under something like [`valgrind`](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html#quick-start.mcrun).  If nothing else it'll give you some useful clues.

Comment: Just run your app for an hour or so, take a live core using gcore and analyze that core using https://github.com/vmware/chap

Comment: It's not clear from your "Why do I know I have memory leaks?" explanation: do you see memory leaks when you repeatedly reading only one file `song.mp3` or only when you read 14M of them? Anyway, even if it does leak while reading `song.mp3`, and even if you'll fix that, there is at least one obvious source of leaks: `return -1` - on any error you free nothing.

Comment: Removing the inclusion of `sndfile.h` and `bits/stdc++.h` makes it possible for more people to compile the program. Never include `bits/stdc++.h` btw.

Comment: What version of `ffmpeg` are you using? As of version 4 `av_register_all()` is deprecated.and you don't need to call anything else.

Comment: I've looked at it a bit and I think you should use another example - or rewrite this from scratch yourself. This example uses more than one deprecated function so I don't think it's worth digging deeper. Also, write RAII wrappers or use a ready C++ ffmpeg wrapper library to make memory management easy.

Comment: @x00 Both, when i run with 14M, the code broke. When i suspect it was due to memory leak problem, i replicated under a controlled setting by re-running the `song.mp3` in a while loop. While the code did not break, i was observing the `htop` and i can verify there is memory build up after 10mins.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks for your comment, i made the necessary changes. removed `sndfile.h`, `bits/stdc++.h`. May i ask why never to include `bits/stdc++.h`? I included it because i followed [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sort-c-stl/) for some sorting function i required.

Also, i included my version : `ffmpeg version 2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1`, `built with gcc 5.4.0`

Comment: @TedLyngmo Can you point me to where can i find a suitable updated script for reading mp3 files using ffmpeg? Also, what do you mean by writing RAII wrappers ?

Comment: `bits/stdc++.h` is a non-standard header (so I couldn't compile your program) and even if it exists it'll include **way** too much. Use the standard headers instead. Aha, ok, with that `ffmpeg` version you do need `av_register_all()` so perhaps the example you use is suitable after all. - 

By a RAII wrapper I mean a wrapper that manages _one_ resource only (and does it good) [untested example](https://godbolt.org/z/xzsodx). It will free the resource when it goes out of scope (like your `return -1;`'s or a `throw`) so it prevents memory leaks.

Comment: Sidenote: The examples on www.geeksforgeeks.org is of varying quality. Any example that proposes inclusion of non-standard headers when there's no need for it shouldn't be taken seriously. To get access to `std::sort` just include the standard `algorithm` header.

Comment: @TedLyngmo wow thanks, im a relatively beginner to c++, and i learnt so much over my brief interactions with you.

Comment: @leonardltk1 That's nice to hear! Thanks!